# How to resolve an xml element using idref

Tags: jquery, xml, resolve, idref

Given some sample `data.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
    <categories>
        <category id="google">
            <name>Google</name>
        </category>
    <categories>
    <display>
        <categories>
            <category idref="google"/>
        </categories>
    </display>
</data>
```

And some jquery code to fetch the `data.xml` file:

```
$.ajax( {
    url: '/data.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function( data )
    {
        $data = $( data );
        // fetch categories to display
        $categories = $data.find( 'display > categories > category' );
    }
} );
```

What is a efficient and compact method to resolve the `category` elements to which the fetched elements in `$categories` refer to by their `idref` attribute?

I've come up with something like the following:

```
$categories.each( function() {
    var $category = $data.find( 'categories > category[id=' + $( this ).attr( 'idref' ) + ']' );
} );
```

But I thought there might be a more compact way of collecting the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create [id selectors](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) from the `idref` attributes:

```
var referenced = $.unique($categories.map(function() {
    var $found = $data.find("#" + $(this).attr("idref"));
    return ($found.length ? $found[0] : null);
}).get());
```

The code above uses [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and [$.unique()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) to build an array containing unique instances of all the referenced `<category>` elements.

Comment: @Tomalak, I'm pretty sure it works with all well-formed XML documents, yes. I created a simple test fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fhamidi/f7v2J/) and the id selector works for me.

Comment: This is very nice also. And of course you can simply create id selectors as well. Why didn't I think of that? ;-)

Comment: @fireeyedboy This is nicer than mine, if it is faster remains a matter of testing. Probably not, in the long run, but depending on your file sizes the difference may be insignificant.

Comment: @Tomalak: Speed is not really an issue for me in this case anyway. But yeah this is a bit cleaner. Although I liked your generic approach. What I want to do now (only just occurred to me) is merge both your ideas in a method to extend jQuery, so I can do something like `$categories.resolveIdRefs()`. Because of this, I don't think I can use `map()` and `unique()`. Maybe I'll start a new question on that, if I don't manage to get it to work. Thank you to the both of you so far!

Answer (score 1):

```
var $data = $( data );
var $byId = {};

$("*[id]", $data).each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  $byId[ $this.attr("id") ] = $this;
});

// later...
$byId["google"].find("name");  //  <name>Google</name>
```

Comment: Ah nice, I like what you did here; resolving all `idref`s in one go. Didn't occur to me to take that route yet.